# Reference to class object property

Tags: javascript

I have class with property `this.eyes`. Code Below. As you can see in first case in `data.num` saved value in second reference. In my project I have no needs to array, so I need somehow to make first sample to save reference like second one. Any idea how?

```js
// Warning! Pseudo Code
// Sample One
class Human {
  constructor() {
    this.eyes = null;
  }
  
  addEye() {
    this.eyes = 1;
  }
}

const william = new Human();
const data = { num: william.eyes }
william.addEye();

// data = { num: null }

// Warning! Pseudo Code
// Sample One
class Human {
  constructor() {
    this.eyes = [];
  }
  
  addEye() {
    this.eyes.push(1);
  }
}

const william = new Human();
const data = { num: william.eyes }
william.addEye();

// data = { num: [1] }
```

Comment: I think your `addEye()` function should be `this.eyes += 1` instead of `this.eyes = 1`.

Comment: If you want `data` to automatically update after calling `william.addEyes()` then either `william` or `addEyes()` will need a reference to `data` since it is outside `Human`'s scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has a small set of built-in types, one of those is `number` which is a "value type" (and as far as I can tell, your `human.eyes` value is always `null` or a `number` value).

JavaScript does not support references to `number` values, so after this `data = { num: william.eyes }` the `data.num` value will be a copy of `william.eyes` and not a reference as you have correctly surmised.

However, JavaScript *does* support non-trivial properties with custom getter/setter logic (`Object.defineProperty`). You could use this, in conjunction with a reference to the `william` object, to have the behaviour you want:

```
const william = new Human();
const data = {}; // new empty object
Object.defineProperty( data, 'num', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    get: function() { return this.human.eyes; },
    set: function(newValue) { this.human.eyes = newValue; }
} );
// Need to give `data` a reference to the `Human`:
data.human = william;

william.addEye();
william.addEye();

console.log( data.num ); // outputs "2"
data.num++;
console.log( william.eyes ); // outputs "3"
```

Answer (score -1):

If I got what you trying to do here correctly , the following should work for you :

```
class Human {
  constructor() {
    this.eyes = 0;
  }

  addEye() {
    this.eyes += 1;
  }
}
```